# How to add :twisted_rightwards_arrows: (emoji) in message commit 'Merge branch'

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, emoji, merge-conflict-resolution

How i can add emjoi `:twisted_rightwards_arrows:` in all the messages that `git merge` creates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the twisted-rightwards-arrow emoji, but here's how to prepand a message to Git's merge commit messages. Put this as your `prepare-commit-msg` hook, so in `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg`, and make sure that it is executable.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$2" = "merge" ]; then
        sed -i "1s/^/ʕ•ᴥ•ʔ /" "$1"
fi
```

As the name implies, Git will call your hook when it prepares a commit message. The first argument `$1` is a file with the commit message in it. We use `sed`'s in-place (-i) mode to substitute (s) the beginning (^) of the first (1) line of that file with a bear's face. The second argument is "merge" if this is a merge commit; if not, we don't touch the commit message.

Here's how it looks:

[image: screenshots]

Of course, you don't have to use a bear. The [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) manual page has more information.